# I need to port the following from C# to C++/CX, but I get a given argument error

Tags: c#, c++, vector, collections, porting

This is what the code in C# looks like:

```
FilterEffect effect = new FilterEffect();
LomoFilter lomoFilter = new LomoFilter();
VignettingFilter vignettingFilter = new VignettingFilter();
effect.Filters = new IFilter[] { lomoFilter, vignettingFilter };

List<IImageProvider> providers = new List<IImageProvider>();
providers.Add(effect);
testSet.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("IImageProviders", providers));
```

This is the code I have for C++ so far:

```
PropertySet ^testSet = ref new Windows::Foundation::Collections::PropertySet();
FilterEffect effect = ref new FilterEffect();
LomoFilter ^lomo = ref new LomoFilter();
Platform::Collections::Vector<IFilter> ^vector = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<IFilter>();
vector->Append(lomo);
effect.Filters = vector;
std::list<IImageProvider> providers;
```

I get the following error at build:

```
        106 IntelliSense: function "Nokia::Graphics::Imaging::FilterEffect::Filters::set" cannot be called with the given argument list
        argument types are: (Platform::Collections::Vector<Nokia::Graphics::Imaging::IFilter, std::equal_to<Nokia::Graphics::Imaging::IFilter>, <error-constant>> ^)
        object type is: Nokia::Graphics::Imaging::FilterEffect ^    c:\Users\Alin Rosu\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\App2Good\AddEffectsBlaApp2\App2\App2\MainPage.xaml.cpp 113 7   App2
```

I'm new to c++/CX so I have no ideea what I have to do here, tried using a std::list instead of the vector, but still nothing. What should I do here, so it will pass the filters without having compiling errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliSense errors are not compilation errors but IDE internal code analysis that may be correct but may be not. If you don't have actual compiler errors you can ignore those or disable them in context menu of errors window.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put "^" at the second line:

```
    FilterEffect ^effect = ref new FilterEffect();
```

Doing that the vector had no problem taking the value, and the code runs